# MsSql Compact, unique constraint on two and more columns

Tags: sql-server-ce

guys! MsSql Compact have feature to create composite unique index (just constraint, not primary key)  on two or more columns both?

col 1 col2
1        2
1        2 - insert/update must generate exception

I don't see this feature via Server Explorer's designer

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ixMultiCol ON MyTable (col1, col2);
```

Comment: Work fine, big tnx. And even via Designer too! - Server Explorer | MyDB | MyTable | Indexes - Context Menu - Create Index., how I skip this feature, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

A unique constraint may use underneath a unique index, but a unique index is NOT a unique constraint. The unique constraint prevents duplicates in the related table columns, while the unique index may just skip the duplicate values quietly.

While the original question was rather about a unique constraint, the correct answer should be:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
   col1 int NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- single-column UNIQUE constraint
   col2 int NULL,

   CONSTRAINT myConstraint UNIQUE (col1, col2) -- multi-column UNIQUE constraint
);
GO
```

A unique index can use a DESC suffix for any column, but a unique constraint in SQL Server CE cannot. Remark also the CONSTRAINT myConstraint part is optional - [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-4.0/ms173393(v=sql.110)).