# How can I define a UNIQUE constraint that applies to multiple columns in a DataSet table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique

I have the following table defined in a .sql script file.

---

```
CREATE TABLE [HwComponent](
    [HwComponentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HwComponentTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ManufactureId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AssignmentType] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [IsFunctional] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_HwComponent] PRIMARY KEY ([HwComponentId]),
    CONSTRAINT (FK1_HwComponent] FOREIGN KEY ([HwComponentTypeId]) REFERENCES [HwComponentType] ([HwComponentTypeId)] ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    CONSTRAINT (FK2_HwComponent] FOREIGN KEY ([HwComponentTypeId], [ManufactureId]) REFERENCES [HwComponentTypeManufacturerInfo] ([HwComponentTypeId], [ManufactureId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT (UI1_HwComponent] UNIQUE ([HwComponentTypeId], [ManufactureId], [SerialNumber]))

GO
```

---

I now need to define a new table in the **DataSet Designer** to match.

I believe I have everything defined correctly, except the UNIQUE constraint that requires all 3 columns be considered together as the unique constraint.

How do I define the UNIQUE constraint for this table in the **DataSet Designer**?

SQL CE Service 4.0 SP1:
VS Prof 2017 - Version 15.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ixYourConstraint ON HwComponent (col1, col2);
```

This similar post might be of help to you: 
[MsSql Compact, unique constraint on two and more columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509422/mssql-compact-unique-constraint-on-two-and-more-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if properly formatted.  You have parens where you shouldn't:

```
CREATE TABLE [HwComponent](
    [HwComponentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HwComponentTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ManufactureId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AssignmentType] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [IsFunctional] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_HwComponent PRIMARY KEY ([HwComponentId]),
    CONSTRAINT FK1_HwComponent FOREIGN KEY ([HwComponentTypeId]) REFERENCES [HwComponentType] ([HwComponentTypeId)] ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    CONSTRAINT K2_HwComponent FOREIGN KEY ([HwComponentTypeId], [ManufactureId]) REFERENCES [HwComponentTypeManufacturerInfo] ([HwComponentTypeId], [ManufactureId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT UI1_HwComponent UNIQUE ([HwComponentTypeId], [ManufactureId], [SerialNumber])
);
```

I would advise you to get rid of all the square braces.  They just make the code harder to write and to read and to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Algef and Gordon for you responses.

Sorry about the confusion. My bad.  :-)
The SQL sample works fine. I used it as an example only. I actually need to represent this table exactly using the **DataSet Designer** in VS. The table should look something like the following when done.

[HwComponent Table in the DataSet Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzf37.jpg)

My problem is I'm not having success in defining the UNIQUE group properly in the **DataSet Designer**. 
I need to define a UNIQUE GROUP that consists of the HwComponentTypeId, ManufactureId and SerialNumber columns.

Any ideas?

Thanks again for any help